# [electron-builder-nsis How Can I Use If-Else To Control MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY?

Tags: windows, electron, windows-installer, nsis, electron-builder

First, Forgive me for my poor English~
Hello, I need finish this question:
If user installed my application, update to application, I want to the install program no show the MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY, if  people never installed, can show MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY.
But Found out I couldn't do it when I write install.nsh.
such as

```
// I want this write
${if} $userInstallPath != ""
   //
${else}
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
${endif}
```

But that's not true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip a page, call `Abort` in the page pre callback. I have no idea how you do this in Electron builder but in normal NSIS you do this:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE dirskip
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
... 

Function dirskip
${If} $userInstallPath != ""
   Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```